# TimeDistributed(Dense()) vs Dense() after lstm

Tags: python, keras, nlp, lstm, tensorflow2.0

```
input_word = Input(shape=(max_len,))
model = Embedding(input_dim=num_words, output_dim=50, input_length=max_len)(input_word)
model = SpatialDropout1D(0.1)(model)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(model)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_tags, activation="softmax"))(model)
#out = Dense(num_tags, activation="softmax")(model)
model = Model(input_word, out)
model.summary()
```

I get the same result when I use just Dense layer or with TimeDistributed. In which case should I use TimeDistributed?

Answer (score 1):

`TimeDistributed` is only necessary for certain layers that cannot handle additional dimensions in their implementation. E.g. `MaxPool2D` only works on 2D tensors (shape `batch x width x height x channels`) and will crash if you, say, add a time dimension:

```
tfkl = tf.keras.layers
a = tf.random.normal((16, 32, 32, 3))
tfkl.MaxPool2D()(a)  # this works

a = tf.random.normal((16, 5, 32, 32, 3))  # added a 5th dimension
tfkl.MaxPool2D()(a)  # this will crash
```

Here, adding `TimeDistributed` will fix it:

```
tfkl.TimeDistributed(tfkl.MaxPool2D())(a)  # works with a being 5d!
```

However, many layers already support arbitrary input shapes and will automatically distribute the computations over those dimensions. One of these is `Dense` -- it is always applied to the last axis in your input and distributed over all others, so `TimeDistributed` isn't necessary. In fact, as you noted, it changes nothing about the output.

Still, it may change how exactly the computation is done. I'm not sure about this, but I would wager that *not* using `TimeDistributed` and relying on the `Dense` implementation itself *may* be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

According to the book Zero to Deep Learning by Francesco Mosconi in chapter 7:

> If we want the model return an output sequence to be compared with the
> sequence of values in the labels, we will use the TimeDistributed
> layer wrapper around our output Dense layer. This method of training
> is called Teacher Forcing. If we didn’t create output sequences we
> wouldn't need Teacher Forcing(i.e. wouldn't need TimeDistributed wrapper).