# What is the difference between TimeDistributed(Conv2D)(input) and Conv2D(input)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I understand that TimeDistributed is used to apply the same layer (with same weights) to each step in a sequence.

I don't understand what is happening when I don't use TimeDistributed.

The keras [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/time_distributed/) shows this example, demonstrating that the output shape has the same number of sequence steps as the input when you use TimeDistributed:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3))
conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
outputs.shape
# TensorShape([None, 10, 126, 126, 64])
```

I get the same output shape when omitting the TimeDistributed wrapper.

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3))
conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
outputs = conv_2d_layer(inputs)
outputs.shape
# TensorShape([None, 10, 126, 126, 64])
```

So what is happening in this second case? Is it just the same thing and TimeDistributed is redundant in this case?

Comment: Based on the last example in https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/, it looks like Conv2D supports multiple batch dimensions.

Comment: @davidli thank you. In that case, it seems Conv2D would be applied to each sample across both batch dimensions. I think that is equivalent to what happens with TimeDistributed, right?

Comment: Yeah it seems like it. I suppose TimeDistributed would be more useful for other layers or just to signal intention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TimeDistributed(Dense()) vs Dense() after lstm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570380/timedistributeddense-vs-dense-after-lstm)